# Contacts Info style table view

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uibutton

I want to reproduce something similar to the image below. How is that created? I can see an `UITableView` and some buttons at the buttons at the bottom, but I can't identify the other UI elements... Also, I tried to add a button to a table view but didn't manage to do so (the table view takes the full space...)

One little detail: I use storyboards, which has its limitations (or so I heard), but I don't have the time to redo the whole project without storyboards.

[image: Contacts info page]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically, the top and the bottom are two custom cells.

[image]

Comment: Ah that makes sense! I managed to remove the background color (white) of the custom cells but can't manage to remove the border/shadow. Any clue on how to do that please?

Comment: Replace the cell.backgroundView with a view with clearColor as backgroundColor, i think this should work

Comment: Right now, that's what I have: http://pastie.org/7898687 and it doesn't do the job... If I'm not mistaken, there is an inner shadow in the cell, but I'm not sure

Comment: That code is probably never called, since you are using prototype cells in the storyboard, right? Put IBOutlets for the first & the last cell and this should be enough: `self.firstCell.backgroundView = [[UIView alloc] init];`

Comment: OK, I'm an idiot. I forgot to link IB's viewController to the viewController file I created, so that code was never called indeed. Sorry about that, and thanks a lot for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

It's just a table with several different kinda of cells. The first section has a single row and uses a cell that could have an image view and a few labels, or it might do all the drawing itself. The next few sections use standard table cells, and the last uses a cell that contains some buttons.

Whether or not you use storyboards shouldn't make a difference here.